# Copy entire row of one worksheet to another based on column A of different worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I'm hoping someone can help with a VBA script as I don't know where to start.

I have three worksheets.

1. WS1 has all of the information for all individual contact info
2. WS2 has column A with everyone's employee number, which is also in column A in WS1.
3. empty

   I would like for some code to go through every row in column A in WS2 and if it exists in Column A in WS1, then copy that entire row from WS1 to WS3.

thanks for any help on this!

Comment: show us please what have you tried so far?

Comment: start working with [vlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) and [hlookup](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/hlookup-HP005209114.aspx). Try these functions without VBA, and once you get how they work, implement them in VBA using the [FormulaR1C1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.namedrange.formular1c1.aspx) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need vba to accomplish this.  Use VLOOKUP formula instead.

Copy the values of Col. A from WS1 into WS3.  Then enter VLOOKUP formulas for as many fields as is necessary.

Comment: I'll start with vlookup to tackle this.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I've been working on this for a couple of days now.  I've been using this as a formula:  '=VLOOKUP(Sheet1!$A:$A,SOURCE!$A:$P,1,FALSE)'  Most are coming back with '#N/A', but they work if:  1)  they exist in the source & 2) if I 'retype' their employee number on the source worksheet in column A.  I guess there is some formatting going with the source.  I obtain the source info from someone else.  The column 'A' in source is formatted as 'text'.  I changed the column to 'general' and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: figured out my problem with my look-up columns.  Select lookup range column and use

Data > text to Columns > Finish